# With CSS, can I increase the contrast of background-image upon hover?

Tags: html, css

I have looked into other threads about this, but they all suggest to play around with opacity and tranparency.

But I want to do the opposite: *increase* contrast of background image (while using the same BG image), or some other way of achieving something similar.

Thanks a lot in advance. Regards

Comment: What do you have so far? Maybe post an example...

Comment: i think the  opacity and transparency is good option, and  there is no need to look for a another option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting the background on top of a plain black background, setting the opacity to 0.8 or 0.9, then setting it to 1.0 on hover.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Never thought of this. Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you're limiting yourself to Webkit, you can use some filter properties you can mess with:

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

If you want more than that... well, it seems each major browser has it's own support for *[something](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content)*  (yes, even [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532853%28v=vs.85%29):  ).  I'm not sure how they could be cobbled together into a comprehensive solution, though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am actually looking for something more universal, but thanks for showing me what can be done with webkit browsers. Regards